# When exactly does a returned const reference get destroyed?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

Lets say I have a function returning an integer by constant reference:

```
const int& five()
{
    return 5;
}
```

I know I shoudn't return a value by reference (`const` or otherwise) which scope is only inside the function but I'm just curious.

Whould it be possible to use the function return as a lvalue like this?

```
int sum = 4 + five();
```

Comment: Have you even tried this?

Comment: @Radosław Cybulski, even `const int &` seems to be a bad idea: `5` is an object, that would be destroyed when you exit the function, but you return reference on it.

Comment: i am not fluent with value categories, so this is a serious question. Why is `five()` an lvalue in `int sum = 4 + five();` ?

Comment: Simple rule of thumb. If it's not *inside the function*, that's UB. `4 + five()` is clearly not inside of `five`.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hKaHiX

Comment: @J.S. you're right, i'm wrong. Unfortunately can't edit my comment anymore.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski you can still delete it ;)

Comment: The reference itself does not get destroyed - it's not an object and does not have a a lifetime. The object that it refers (referred) to gets destroyed when the function returns.

Comment: If you all don't mind, given there is not an answer yet, I've changed the return type of the function to make things more interesting. Roll back though if the community judges my action to be in poor taste.

Comment: @Bathsheba I dont mind your edit, but the top comment is now even more misleading. Anyhow, a good answer should clarify that ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: I've flagged that comment for deletion. My edit is legitimate in the sense that the original question was non-compilable in standard C++ (although some compilers allow the non-`const` binding).

Comment: @molbdnilo: Absolutely. C++ is not a "try and if it works it must be ok" type of language.

Comment: "Scope" is for identifiers. Objects don't have a scope by definition.

Comment: *Whould it be possible* No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects created within the scope of a function are destroyed when that function returns.  The returned reference is no longer valid by the time control returns to the call site.

That means that the function definition in your question is not valid.  It returns a reference to an object that will be gone by the time anything has a chance to use the returned reference.

---

It may be worth it to note that temporary objects returned by *value* live until the end of the full expression.  So for the following code:

```
struct Test
{
    Test() { std::cout << "Test constructed\n"; }
    ~Test() { std::cout << "Test destroyed\n"; }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Test& t) {
    os << "Test output";
    return os;
}

Test func() {
    return {};
}

int main() {
    std::cout << func() << "\nAfter\n";
}
```

The output would be:

> ```
> Test constructed
> Test output
> After
> Test destroyed
> ```

Because the `Test` object returned by `func` lives until the end of the full `cout` expression.